# Clone another branch after cloning single-branch

Tags: git, branch, git-clone, git-checkout

I'm using the below command to clone one branch:

```
git clone user@git-server:project_name.git -b branch_name --single-branch /your/folder
```

Now I want to check out another branch from the server. I tried the below command and it didn't work

```
git checkout another_branch
```

After cloning a single branch, how can I clone/checkout/pull/fetch another branch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fetch another remote branch by specifying it after the remote name in a `git fetch` call:

```
git fetch origin another_branch
```

Once it's fetched, you'll find it in the `FETCH_HEAD`, and an use that to create a local branch:

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -b another_branch
```

Answer (score 16):

Besides [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70392801/1256452)—which is good for some "one-off" / short-term work cases—you can also use `git remote` to add additional branches, or update your single-branch clone to an all-branch clone:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin another-branch
```

After this, `git fetch origin` will create the remote-tracking name `origin/another-branch`, which will allow `git checkout another-branch` to invoke the `--guess` mode to create your (local) branch name `another-branch` from your remote-tracking name `origin/another-branch`.

To de-single-branch-ize a clone, use:

```
git remote set-branches origin "*"
```

(followed by `git fetch` as usual).

Note that whether you *need* to quote the asterisk depends on your command-line-interpreter, but in general it's *safe* to do it.